# Cookie creation using mod_rewrite failure

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies

I need to create a Cookie using mod_rewrite. Found the needed flag here;

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Used this in my virtualhost config file but no cookies are set. I've found some examples, but none of them work for my serv.

Since I thought maybe the virtualhost was creating a problem, I added an htaccess file with the following configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [CO=frontdoor:yes:.perfil.com:1440:/]
```

Once again, no cookie is set. The RewriteRule is matched, but no cookie is created.

Please help!

EDIT: apache v2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am 99% sure, that you are misspelled the domain.

```
# curl -I http://somedomain.dev/q/more-stuff
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Wed, 22 Jan 2014 01:41:42 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (FreeBSD) PHP/5.4.11
Set-Cookie: frontdoor=yes; path=/; domain=.perfil.com; expires=Thu, 23-Jan-2014 01:41:42 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

As you can see the header is sent, but the browser does not accept it since the domains do not match.